# How to encrypt / decrypt a number into a string without using Base64

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cryptography

I have a number (int, long, double types) and I want to encrypt that number into a string with "alphabet or number" or "both alphabet and number" (non special characters).

Because I want to encrypt the UserId in a Url.
I have seen some posts on the internet, but they always return a Base64 string, however I don't want to show Base64 string in Url.

P/s: I want encrypt / decrypt, NOT encode / decode.

Comment: `string myString = myNumber.toString()`?

Comment: I think it's very important to be clear if you need to **encrypt** or **encode**. They are very different things

Comment: Encryption functions produce streams of bytes (0-255). Because you can't use certain characters (notably anything less than 32) in your URL they are converted to base64. Why do you NOT want to use base64?

Comment: You don't want to use Base64 because... reasons. So could you use [Base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) instead?  Once you've done the encryption you're going to need some way of encoding bytes into strings, so pick your encoding and implement it.

Comment: What you need is encrypt-then-encode, and decode-then-decrypt. You need both.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a text based cypher, but I haven't ever heard of anyone. The best way to solve your problem is to combine encryption and base64 encoding. You encrypt the userid with a cypher of your choice (for example AES) and then you base64 encode the encrypted byte array to get a string representation.